# Redirect 301 dynamic-URL to 404 error-page with htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404, dynamic-url

Can someone help me to get the correct .htaccess rules for:

Redirect this specific ID url:

```
http://www.domain.com/watch.php?id=00000000001
```

to my 404 error page:

```
http://www.domain.com/404/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=00000000001$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^watch\.php$ /404/? [NC,L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for reply @anubhava , I tested your code but unfortunately not works for me. Is there any alternative rule?

Comment: What is location of above .htaccess? Are there more rules OR just this rule? Are .htaccess and mod_rewrite enabled?

Comment: I solved modifying your original code. I don't know if these rules are entirely correct but it seems to work fine:   

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/watch\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=00000000001$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http//www.domain.com/404/ [L,R=301]`

Comment: What you have can be quite simplified with the rule in my latest update. Also if it works out consider marking it as accepted.